# How to change keyboard shortcut for "log out"?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I use a third party app for alt-tab, so when I hit alt+shift+tab+Q, the operating system doesn't recognize it as quitting the app. Instead it recognizes it as the log out keyboard command. (The native OSX alt+shift+tab+q will quit the app, however.)

I figure this could easily be resolved if I could change the keyboard shortcut.

OSX 10.7.5, Macbook Pro mid-2011.

Answer (score 1):

You could try changing ⌥⇧⌘Q to ⌥⌘Q with [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<item>
<name>test</name>
<identifier>private.test</identifier>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::Q, VK_OPTION | VK_SHIFT | VK_COMMAND, KeyCode::Q, VK_COMMAND | VK_OPTION</autogen>
</item>
</root>
```

Comment: Is this going to mess with the kernel? I was hoping for a safer way to do it.